# .htaccess : understanding use of deny,allow and allow,deny

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server-configuration

I'm trying to understand with a short test example how the `order deny,allow` statements reacts looking to what I've read untill now.

I have the following site structure for testing :

/index.htm
/.htaccess (1)
/subfolder/index.htm
/subfolder/.htaccess (2)

**.htaccess (1)**

```
order deny,allow  
allow from all
```

**subfolder/.htaccess (2)**

```
order deny,allow  
deny from all
```

No matter the order I use for allow,deny / deny,allow (and all 4 possible combinations) in the 2 .htaccess files, I'm never allowed to access the subfolder/index.htm.

As far as I've understood, there is at least one combination where the root `allow from all` wins on the subfolder `deny from all`, so I don't understand why I can't succeed doing this on that so simple example.

Can you explain why and what's happening ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Order Directive

The rules `order deny,allow` and `order allow,deny` define in which order the `deny from` and `allow from` directives are processed. All allow and deny rules are processed, with the final relevant rule overriding any previous rules. See the [Order Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) section of the mod_authz_host module documentation for confirmation.

> Note that all Allow and Deny directives are processed, unlike a
>   typical firewall, where only the first match is used. The last match
>   is effective (also unlike a typical firewall). Additionally, the order
>   in which lines appear in the configuration files is not significant --
>   all Allow lines are processed as one group, all Deny lines are
>   considered as another, and the default state is considered by itself.

For example, if we process the deny rules before the allow rules, we can effectively creating a whitelist of allowed IP addresses.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Conversely, in the following example, we process the allow rules, before the deny rules, for a blacklist of denied IP addresses.

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 127.0.0.1
```

## Inheritance

Subdirectories will inherit the rules of parent directories, unless they declare their own rules. If a subdirectory uses either an order directive or an allow/deny directive, the rules from the parent are not inherited. See [Bug 52406](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52406) which refers to the [Merging of configuration sections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html#merging) section of this document, for confirmation of this behavior.

> For modules that don't implement any merging logic, such as
>   mod_access_compat, the behavior in later sections depends on whether
>   the later section has any directives from the module. The
>   configuration is inherited until a change is made, at which point the
>   configuration is replaced and not merged.

#### Simple Test

You can also do this simple test to confirm this behavior.

Put the following lines in the parent directory `.htaccess`.

```
order deny,allow  
deny from all
```

And any or all of the following lines in the child directory `.htaccess`.

```
order deny,allow  
deny from 0.0.0.0
```

You will see the the child directory is now publicly accessible, even though the parent directory contains `deny from all` and the child directory has no `allow from` directives.

## Conclusion

Based on the documentation and experimentation, it seems that it is impossible for a parent directory to override a child director's directives in any way.

Comment: Hmmmm... yes, ok, that's what I've read almost everywhere. But what about my question ? :-)

Comment: @Oliver Your question of what combination will enable the parent to override the child? As I said and proved with my example, apparently none.

Comment: Tell me, in you rfirst example, if you process the deny rules before the allow rules, as far as I see, it does not creates a white list but deny the access for all. To create a white list, you should order the allow before the deny. Isn't it ? Same thing for the second example, but in the opposite way.

Comment: You say that adding a deny,allow command resets the inheritance from the parent ones. Could you point me to some solid documentation about this ? That's also what I see, but I don't find a word about this...

Comment: So in your first example, inverting the order directive is equivalent as writing just a deny for all, is it ?

Comment: @Oliver Correct! If you tell it to process deny rules after allow, and you have a deny from all, you will universally deny everyone, regardless of any allow directives.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

Using `deny, allow` directives is deprecated since Apache 2.4 [as mentioned here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/access.html).

So now the right directive that allow all access would be

```
Require all granted
```

And to be able to revoke access to a given IP

```
Require all granted
Require not ip 10.345.67.892
```